# Why pandas dataframe shows error when identifying a column?

Tags: python, pandas

When using [this simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16476974/4451521)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [10, 11, 12], 'c2': [100, 110, 120]})

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['c1'], row['c2'])
```

There is no problem in writing　`row['c1']`.
However when I have a csv file like

```
t, p1, p2, p3, p4, vis
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 10
2, 0.1, 0, 0, 0.9, 12
3, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.8, 15
4, 0.2, 0.3, 0, 0.5 ,18
```

and I do

```
df3 = pd.read_csv('test2.csv', index_col=0)
print(df3)
```

I got

```
    p1   p2   p3   p4   vis
t                          
1  0.0  0.0    0  1.0    10
2  0.1  0.0    0  0.9    12
3  0.2  0.0    0  0.8    15
4  0.2  0.3    0  0.5    18
```

so far so good, right?
However when I try to do this

```
print(df3['vis'])
```

I got an error. I cannot do either `df3[0]`
Why is this happening and how can I get the column?

Comment: What is `print(df3.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: There is a leading space. Can you check `df3[' vis']`?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Oh mine! I cannot believe spaces are that crucial. So doe s this originate because the cvs had spaces?

Comment: @KansaiRobot - Yes, it's a common cause of error.